# How to know if this Java's string.replaceAll is executed or not?

Tags: java, replaceall

if i have some string e.g:

```
String s = "This is a string";
```

And now i perform this action:

```
s = s.replaceAll("This","What");
```

It works, with s = "What is a string"

fine, but now if the expression was not a match:

```
s = s.replaceAll("junk","What");
```

s remains what it was before, i.e `s = "This is a string";`

---

I want to know, without equating these strings, is there a way to know if s.replaceAll really performed some action or not??

Comment: No. Just check for equality. You *may* be able to check for reference identity, but I wouldn't rely on that unless it's documented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

would it be ok if you try

```
if(s.contains("junk")) 
  s.replaceAll("junk", "What"); 
else 
  //you know it hasn't executed!
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking if there is some way other than using `s.equals(...)`, then the answer is no there is not.

The javadoc does not state that `replaceAll` will return the target object if no characters were changed, so even if it did that should be treated as an implementation detail; i.e. `==` **should not** be used as a short-cut if you cared about portability.

---

Of course, you can test if the match regex matches the original string, and use that to determine if a replacement would have been performed.  But even if you know that the replacement has occurred, that doesn't tell you whether or not the replacement action actually changed the string.  (And determining that is hard ... if you need to consider the case that the replacement string contains group references.)

Answer (score 0):

Since `replaceAll`uses `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)` behind the screens, you could use some of the `Matcher` methods to find out if any replacement would happen. But it really depends on how you wish to use it. Why don't you want to compare the strings in the first place?